# What is the link to my default "archive" page?

Tags: templates, archives, links

I'm using twentyten and have overloaded home.php to do some custom stuff. However, I would still like to have a page that lists all of my recent posts, archive-style.

I can get to an archive page for any given category with myblog/category/category-name.

But I'd like to get to an archive that just lists all recent posts, regardless of category. Like myblog/archive

Am I assuming too much? I know I can create a custom page template and then create a custom page and apply that template. I just thought that wordpress had a built-in "archives" page, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no "full archive" page like you describe created by default. This would basically be the twentyten index page set to display "your latest posts." If you don't want to access the archives via some sort of filter (category, author, year, month etc.) then you will need to create your own archive template and page like you described above. you could also use the twentyten index.php as the basis for your new template.

So you can create the archive page, set it to use your new template and use the url myblog/archive like you wanted.

Comment: Okay, sounds like I was dreaming when I thought you could get to some kind of built-in archive page. My question was a bit of a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

From the Codex: [Creating an Archives Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index).

Basically:

1. Create a custom template file.
2. Create a static Page.
3. Assign the custom template to the static Page

Comment: Yea, that's basically what I said in my OP.

Comment: Right, but did you read the link I posted? It gives examples for how to build your custom template for outputting post archives.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Updated 2018: Latest Version of Wordpress Heirarchy]

Updated 2018: Latest Version of Wordpress Heirarchy

Answer (score -1):

According to this image, the file you want is archive.php categories have there own file along with others
[image: WordPress Template Hierarchy]
[Link to the image](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

The Twentyten template uses all of the features WordPress offers as an example of what you can make your theme do

Comment: Lastly you should also consider creating two blank pages in wordpress one named home and another named blog, news whatever you want then go to your settings tab and in the reading settings there should be a option for static pages one for home or front page and the other for posts take your two new pages you just created and select them in the appropriate drop downs then save.

Comment: although to know the template can be useful, there is no way to directly link to the template.

Comment: Please do not down vote something that was an aid. If you continued reading my post you would have seen that i said create a new template and use the static pages which is the common way of doing this.

Comment: Your response doesn't actually address the question - if you try typing www.myblog.com/blog/archive.php you get an error. Also, the Reading settings you describe do nothing more than change the way your home page functions.